# Rails 3 cross subdomain flash message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is it possible to set a flash[:notice] message that would be set in a controller on www.example.com but would be read and rendered on client.example.com?

In this particular instance, www.example.com and client.example.com are in the same Rails 3.2 application.

A user is coming in via www.example.com/signup, completing a form and then being redirect to a newly created subdomain client.example.com.

Can you do something like:

```
flash[:notice] = "hello world", domain: "*.example.com"
```

Comment: There is a lot of information missing: Is it just the same application for example. If you create a message in the db that is deleted as soon as it is getting sent, then you can all sorts of things. You may also send them via http or whatdoiknow... Give us some more to work with, please.

Comment: The rails flash does no accomplish that. But in that very case you would create some sort of session with the user. If the session cookie is for .example.com the session can be shared as the session cookie is available to both subdomains. You then either can send information within the session or store the message for later use in the databse and just have a lookup when a logged in user comes to the welcome page of the client subdomain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash does not support this out of the box.  If you want to do something like this you'll need to set a cookie on the domain and then retrieve it from the subdomain.

You need to set the domain of the cookie so that is accessible in the subdomain.  Here is an example you can put in your environment file or an initializer better yet!:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_my_key', :domain => ".yourdomain.com"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - this seemed to do the trick, although it does not work in localhost, but i'm sure that it just due to the local domain(s) I have setup.

Comment: Ya, I think all bets are off with localhost setup.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to ensure your session can be shared across all subdomains. Open `config/initializers/session_store.rb` and add the `:domain => :all` option:

```
Yourapp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_yourapp_session', :domain => :all
```

Comment: Thanks for the response as well - same answer as @weexpectedTHIS but yours came in a few min after.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that does not require the sharable sessions across subdomains is by sending the message as a request parameter

```
# application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController
  before_action :handle_cross_domain_flash_messages

  def handle_cross_domain_flash_messages
    flash.alert = params[:alert] if params[:alert]
    flash.notice = params[:notice] if params[:notice]
  end
end
```

Now you can use any path with `:alert` or `:notice` params to set the flash messages:

```
# example path
'/?alert=Hello+World'
```

```
# example controller
class PagesController
  def redirect_with_message
    redirect_to root_path(notice: 'Hello world')
  end
end
```

However, doing this leaves the parameters in the address bar of the browser. Personally, I don't like super long addresses in the address bar. A way to remove the params from the address bar while still getting the desired flash messages is by redirecting.

```
# application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController
  before_action :handle_cross_domain_flash_messages

  def handle_cross_domain_flash_messages
    return unless params[:alert] || params[:notice]
    redirect_to request.path, alert: params[:alert], notice: params[:notice]
  end
end
```

**Step by step explanation:**

1. The controller action from the 3rd code block would redirect us to `'/?notice=Hello+world'`.
2. The `handle_cross_domain_flash_messages` will see that a flash message was passed through the parameters and will cause another redirect, and will pass the flash messages it was given.
3. The redirect will go to `'/'` now, a clean path in the browser. The flash messages are on the page.

It did take an extra redirect but hey, no global sessions were used.